# Android java room database, app building error

Tags: java, android, android-room

I've created a sample room database app.

is the error showing for any dependency error?? or something for JDK???

when i run this error showing:

```
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.Identifier found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$AdjustableOrientation found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$BoxLayoutAxis found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$CalendarMonth found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$CursorType found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$FlowLayoutAlignment found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$FontStyle found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$HorizontalAlignment found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$InputEventMask found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$ListSelectionMode found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$PatternFlags found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$TabLayoutPolicy found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$TabPlacement found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$TitledBorderJustification found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$TitledBorderTitlePosition found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$TreeSelectionMode found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.Language found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.MagicConstant found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.Pattern found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.PrintFormat found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.PrintFormatPattern found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.RegExp found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0)
Duplicate class org.intellij.lang.annotations.Subst found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0)
Duplicate class org.jetbrains.annotations.Nls found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0)
Duplicate class org.jetbrains.annotations.NonNls found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0)
Duplicate class org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0)
Duplicate class org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0)
Duplicate class org.jetbrains.annotations.PropertyKey found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0)
Duplicate class org.jetbrains.annotations.TestOnly found in modules jetified-annotations-12.0 (com.intellij:annotations:12.0) and jetified-annotations-13.0 (org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0)

Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.
```

here is the dependencies im using for this project.
hope you can solve this please....
DEPECDENCY :

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.1'

    // Room Components
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.4.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-testing:2.4.0-beta01'

    // Lifecycle Components
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.4.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

Comment: Can you post your related gradle files? It might be a mix up of using api vs implementation for dependencies.

Comment: Sorry for that.. i was in hurry. Edited and inserted dependency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your gradle file the dependency

`implementation 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.0-beta01'`

needs to be

`annotationProcessor 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.0-beta01'`

Here is the support documents for room.

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room

As a side note I would avoid using a beta version unless you are truly dependent on a new feature that was added or a bug fix.

Comment: im not using beta dependency, added just for error solving.. :)